# Rotate the Activity with click on a Button

Tags: android, button, screen-rotation

I am using this CODE to disable the auto rotate in my App:

```
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

What I want is to write a CODE inside my Activity to make the App on **portrait** or **landscape** as the user want by clicking a button and save it in SharedPreferences.

I am already made **layout** and **layout-land** with different design but as i disabled it in my Manifest its is not showing up, Cause i want the users chose what they want!

Thanks for any Help

UPDATE

```
    /** Here is the Rotation Button */
View.OnClickListener mb2 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(".ABOUT"));
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    }
};
```

It doesn't work this way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

or

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```